# $A,B,C$ and $D$ are concyclic.$AC$ is the diameter of the circle and $AD=DC$.The area of quadrilateral $ABCD$ is $20cm^2$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles, area

$A,B,C$ and $D$ are concyclic . $AC$ is the diameter of the circle and $AD=DC$ . The area of quadrilateral $ABCD$ is $20c$m$^2$.

Draw a line $DE$ such that $E$ is a point on $AB$, and $DE$ $\bot$ $AB$.
Find the length of $DE$.
The answer keys says that it is ${2}\sqrt{5}$ $cm$.  How was the length found?

I imagine that the use of similar triangles and using the fact that angle in a semicircle is $90^\circ $may be involved, but I cannot go beyond that.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Typo? $AD = AC$ but $AC$ is diameter, while $D$ is also on the circle. This forces $C=D$.

Comment: Yes, I agree there is some typo. @Han Myo Htet make sure you copied it correctly .

Comment: @player3236 I have edited it,sorry.

Comment: @HanMyoHtet , what are your thoughts on this problem? Please show us your work in the question.

Comment: @Han Myo Htet I got $2\sqrt5$. Maybe there is a tyou in your answer?

Comment: I am deeply sorry, I have edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]E is out side of side AB. Draw a perpendicular from D on BC and mark it as F. Quadrilateral DEBF is square, so $EE=BF$. Triangles DFC and DEA are equal because two sides  of them DC=AD and DF=DE. So we cut the triangle DFC and add it to DABF on side AD to costruct triangle ADE. This means the area of ABCD is equal to the rea of square DEBF, therefor $DE=\sqrt {20}=2\sqrt 5$

Comment: Very nice your proof! +1

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very simple too.

Comment: Please don't mind me for asking, but how do we know that DEBF is a square?

Comment: @HanMyoHtet, because angles ABF, DFB and BED are right angles(90 degrees), so the fourth angle i.e. EDF is $90^o$ and also DE=DF that is two adjacent sides are equal, hence ABFD is square.

Answer (score 2):

Let $AB=x$ and $BC=y$.

Thus, $$AC=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ and by the given:
$$\frac{xy}{2}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{4}=20,$$ which gives $$x+y=4\sqrt5.$$
Id est,  $$DE=AD\sin\left(45^{\circ}+\measuredangle BAC\right)=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\left(\sin\arctan\frac{y}{x}+\cos\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right)=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\left(\frac{\frac{y}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)=2\sqrt5.$$